# use another language message from dektrium yii2 users

Tags: yii2, yii-extensions, yii-components, yii2-user

I want use another language message in  dektrium yii2 users
this plugin have "fa_IR' language messege but i cant change language message from english to another language

I think i must change language from here but dosnt work :

```
 'user' => [
            'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
            'sourceLanguage' => 'fa-IR',
            'languages' =>'fa-IR',
        ],
```

This is message.php in messege folder :

```
<?php

return [
    'sourcePath' => __DIR__ . '/../',
    'messagePath' => __DIR__,
    'languages' => [
        'ca',
        'da',
        'de',
        'es',
        'fa-IR',
        'fi',
        'fr',
        'hr',
        'hu',
        'it',
        'kz',
        'lt',
        'nl',
        'pt-BR',
        'pt-PT',
        'ro',
        'ru',
        'th',
        'tr_TR',
        'uk',
        'vi',
        'zh-CN',
    ],
    'translator' => 'Yii::t',
    'sort' => false,
    'overwrite' => true,
    'removeUnused' => false,
    'only' => ['*.php'],
    'except' => [
        '.svn',
        '.git',
        '.gitignore',
        '.gitkeep',
        '.hgignore',
        '.hgkeep',
        '/messages',
        '/tests',
        '/vendor',
    ],
    'format' => 'php',
];
```

This is docs from user plugin:
https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user/blob/master/docs/README.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

config/main.php

```
return [
    'language' => 'fa-IR',
    ....
    'components' => [...]
];
```

DON'T CHANGE THE SOURCE CODE.